# Is there a way to pipe from a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find all files in a file structure above a certain file size, list them, then delete them. What I currently have looks like this:

```
filesToDelete=$(find $find $1 -type f -size +$2k -ls)
if [ -n "$filesToDelete" ];then
echo "Deleting files..."
echo $filesToDelete
$filesToDelete | xargs rm
else 
echo "no files to delete"
fi
```

Everything works, except the $filesToDelete | xargs rm, obviously. Is there a way to use pipe on a variable? Or is there another way I could do this? My google-fu didn't really find anything, so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the information everyone. I will post the working code here now for anyone else stumbling upon this question later:

```
if [ $(find $1 -type f -size +$2k | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; then
find $1 -type f -size +$2k -exec sh -c 'f={}; echo "deleting file $f"; rm $f' {} \;
else
echo "no files above" $2 "kb found"
fi
```

Comment: Why don't you handle everything from the `find` command? `find ... -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: @fedorqui I might add that I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Bash and anything Linux related. I tried adding -exec rm {} \ at the end of the find, and that just throws errors in my face (unexpected EOF, syntax error, etc.).

That said, if I delete them as part of setting filesToDelete, will I be able to print the list afterwards (considering they've been, well, deleted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `-exec` to perform an action on the files that were found in `find`:

```
find $1 -type f -size +$2k -exec rm {} \;
```

The `-exec` trick makes `find` execute the command given for each one of the matches found. To refer the match itself we have to use `{} \;`.

If you want to perform more than one action, `-exec sh -c "..."` makes it. For example, here you can both print the name of the files are about to be removed... and remove them. Note the `f={}` thingy to store the name of the file, so that it can be used later on in `echo` and `rm`:

```
find $1 -type f -size +$2k -exec sh -c 'f={}; echo "removing $f"; rm $f' {} \;
```

---

In case you want to print a message if no matches were found, you can use `wc -l` to count the number of matches (if any) and do an `if / else` condition with it:

```
if [ $(find $1 -type f -size +$2k | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; then
   find $1 -type f -size +$2k -exec rm {} \;
else
   echo "no matches found"
fi
```

`wc` is a command that does `w`ord `c`ount (see `man wc` for more info). Doing `wc -l` counts the number of `l`ines. So `command | wc -l` counts the number of lines returned by `command`.

Then we use the `if [ $(command | wc -l)  -ge 1 ]` check, which does an integer comparison: if the value is `g`reater or `e`qual to `1`, then do what follows; otherwise, do what is in `else`.

---

Buuuut the previous approach was using `find` twice, which is a bit inefficient. As `-exec sh -c` is opening a sub-shell, we cannot rely on a variable to keep track of the number of files opened. Why? Because a sub-shell cannot assign values to its parent shell.

Instead, let's store the files that were deleted into a file, and then count it:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'f={}; echo "$f" >> /tmp/findtest; rm $f' {} \;
if [ -s /tmp/findtest ]; then #check if the file is empty
    echo "file has $(wc -l < /tmp/findtest) lines"
    # you can also `cat /tmp/findtest` here to show the deleted files
else
    echo "no matches"
fi
```

Note that you can `cat /tmp/findtest` to see the deleted files, or also use `echo "$f"` alone (without redirection) to indicate while removing. `rm /tmp/findtest` is also an option, to do once the process is finished.

Comment: What does 'f={];' do? Except for that I think I kind of understand it

Comment: `{}` is the way to refer to the name of the file that was found. So with `f={}` we store it in a variable, so that we can use it to both `echo` and `rm`.

Comment: Well, that ended up working as far as deleting goes, but it didn't echo anything.

Comment: @user2875994 strange. This works fine to me: ` find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'f={}; echo "hello $f"; rm $f' {} \;` . You can also use the first approach twice: firstly without `-exec rm {} \;` to get the list of files; then, with it, to remove them.

Comment: Nevermind, worked as soon as I didn't set it as a variable (why would that make it not echo, though?).

That said, I need to give a message when it doesn't find any files, which doesn't seem to work with this solution.

Comment: Ok I combined your last example with the sh -c and that works.

Could you explain the wc -l / -ge 1? It works, but I don't really understand how/why. 

Except for that, thanks for a very thorough explanation!

Edit: I'm not new to stack overflow (just new account because I have no idea where my old one is). I will mark as accepted, I just like to get to the bottom of the problem before I do so.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it perfectly now.

My last question would be: at the moment, the code repeats the find.. blablasize twice. This seems a bit redundant. Is there a way to reduce this?

Also, I'm not new to stack overflow, only Bash/Linux ;)

Comment: @user2875994 for this you can combine my solution with choroba's. That is, you do `files=$(find ...)` and then `if [ ! -z "$files" ]; then ... xargs rm <<< "$files"`; else echo "no matches found"; fi. That is, you store the results into a var, check if the variable is empty and then decide what to do.

Comment: Hmn, that actually seems just as complex (if not more). Oh well, guess I'll use it as it is right now, then. It's just the part of me that has coded a lot in C# etc. screams in agony at the redundancy ;) I'll update my question with the working code now.

Comment: @user2875994 you kept me thinking and yes, you are right, using `find` twice is a bit inefficient. I just added another approach, in which we store the values found into a file and then check if the file has any content.

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out, you don't need piping a var in this case. But just in case you needed it in some other situation, you can use

```
xargs rm <<< $filesToDelete
```

or, more portably

```
echo $filesToDelete | xargs rm
```

Beware of spaces in file names.

To also output the value together with piping it, use `tee` with process substitution:

```
echo "$x" | tee >( xargs rm )
```

Comment: I tried your second example, and it works (if I remove -ls from the find). The problem is... when I do that, it doesn't actually print/echo the removed files. I can do echo two times (one with and without xargs rm), but it seems kinda redundant... Well, at least it works.

Comment: tee looks interesting. Can you use tee to run | xargs rm in the find statement, but keep the list of files as the variable?

Comment: I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have the rep to do that on this account. Regardless, thanks for the information!

Comment: +1 because you're the only who answered the OP's question - _how to pipe from a variable_ ;) :)

Comment: @user2875994: I don't understand. You mean you want to use the `find | xargs` syntax, but sneak the `tee` in to populate a variable? It's not possible, as the `>(...)` part happens in a subshell, so any changes to variables there are inaccessible for the parent. Maybe you could switch to `printf -v`, but still, you are in a middle of a pipeline, i.e. in a subshell.

Comment: @choroba
When I googled tee, it said it was used to execute a command but store the information of the command being passed/piped on. So I assumed I could pipe it to rm but keep the list using tee somehow, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all this. You can directly use `find` command to get the files over a particular size limit and delete it using xargs.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(find $1 -type f -size +$2k | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No Files to delete"
else
    echo "Deleting the following files"
    find $1 -size +$2 -exec ls {} \+
    find $1 -size +$2 -exec ls {} \+ | xargs rm -f
    echo "Done"
fi
```

Comment: I realize that, but I want to print/echo the list as well (if it exists). That's where the hiccups start.

Comment: I do understand your requirement that is why I used `/usr/bin/find <directory path> -size +<size limit> -exec ls -lh {} \+` in my answer. Use this command to list the files. For example, `/usr/bin/find $1 -size +$2k -exec ls -lh {} \+`

Comment: Seems like your edit is very close to what fedorqui explained to me (edited into OP), although it ha a bit more redundancy. Regardless, thanks for helping. Sadly I cannot upvote due to the account being new.